# Getting primitive info of an object within a method java

Tags: java, arraylist

So In a separate program I declared an object called dragon like this:

```
public Dragon(int color, int location, boolean breathesFire) {
    this.color = color;
    this.location = location;
    this.breathesFire = breathesFire;
  }
```

now I want to make a method to act on a specific dragon within an arraylist  of dragons in order to change one of its primitives like color.

So i wrote :

```
public void changeColor(int i) {
    int j = (int) Math.random() * 7; 
    int k = this.location;
    boolean o = this.breathesFire;
    army.set(i, j, k, o);
  }
```

Which is suppose to change the color of "i"th dragon in the array list (their are 6 colors so Math.random * 7 rounded down would give you a random one). Anyways it doesn't  compile and has various errors, any tips/solutions?

Comment: If your code doesn't compile and you need help -- show the full error message.

Comment: Paste all the required code. What object is army referring to and what does set method logic do?

Comment: You have to post the errors that you are getting. Your question is not clear. Try to reformulate your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should not declare such a method in the Dragon class. Declare it rather in the class containing the ArrayList object.
The first thing you should do is receive the i'th dragon from the array list.
Then you should use Getters for the members of Dragon.

```
    int j = (int) Math.random() * 7; 
    Dragon dragon = yourArrayList.get(i);
    int k = dragon.getLocation();
    boolean o = dragon.isBreathingFire();
    army.set(i, j, k, o);
```

The Getters (declared in the Dragon class) would be

```
    public boolean isBreathingFire() {
        return breathesFire;
    }

   public int getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
```

That's all i can think of. For more help we would need the full error message.